# Delete TextBox Text value when DropDownList index changes

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, web-parts, asp.net-3.5

I have a web part with a quite long form, but for the example, let's only use the DropDownList (DDL) and TextBox (TB). I would like to remove the value of the TB when the DDL's index changes.

**Ascx content**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStep0" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DdlStep0SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />

<asp:TextBox ID="txtStep0" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" />
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.PopulateDDLStep0(); // populates the DDL with ListItems, I believe it does not matter how
    }
}

protected void DdlStep0SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtStep0.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

I would expect the code above to work as expected. However, the Text value is not deleted when I change the DDL selection. It simply doesn't change.

**EDIT**
The postback is necessary since there are some more changes connected to the index change, e.g. there are 4 more DDLs and their value changes, too.

Comment: How does textbox receive its value?

Comment: This code works. You sure you have the right textbox name?

Comment: @Andrei User sets the value, nothing else.

Comment: @sjramsay I checked twice, are you sure you use asp .net 3.5?

Comment: No, I used 4.5 but this code should be no different.

Comment: So you have a user control and this code behind is in the code behind of the user control?

Comment: Well, there could be a bug. Anyway, I debugged it and the event handler is called properly after the page_load. It might be important that the code is actually in a user control which is the body of a sharepoint 2010 web part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63045/discussion-between-santhos-and-sjramsay).

Comment: @sjramsay Don't forget to post your answer, that is the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an UpdatePanel to refresh your User Control

Answer (score 1):

I think so you should have to remove`AutoPostBack="True"` and used

`if (!isPostback) {this.txtStep0.Text = string.Empty;}`

Comment: I probably haven't explained the scenario that well - see my edit -, but this does not work (for me) and I also believe that it must be achievable when the auto post back is on.